# PicklingError for ProcessPoolExecutor

Tags: python, pickle, python-multiprocessing, concurrent.futures

I have already implemented a programm, where it gets a path with hundreds of pdf-files. It than opens them and extracts informations. But this takes a while, so i wanted to implement the ProcessPoolExecutor.

```
import concurrent.futures
import os


def func(path):
    print(path)
    return path

path = r'C:\Users\abi52\OneDrive\Desktop\Pyprogramme\SDBS'
listPaths= os.listdir(path)
listPathsFinal = []

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for PDF in listPaths:
        if 'pdf' in PDF or 'PDF' in PDF:
            listPathsFinal.append(r'%s\%s' %(path,PDF))

    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as ex:
        result = ex.map(func,listPathsFinal)

    print(list(result))
```

**func** should just show if the paths are given to the function. But when i list the result it shows a Pickling error. There are already similar questions asked but for the most part they describe functions which are not top level, e.g. function in a class. But this minimalistic function should be top level, so i don't understand the error. I am relatively new to programming so i would appreciate your help.

```
listPathsFinal = ['C:\\Users\\abi52\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Pyprogramme\\SDBS\\MSDS_Merck_Chloroform für die Flüssigkeitschromatographie LiChrosolv®_10.05.2021.PDF', 'C:\\Users\\abi52\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Pyprogramme\\SDBS\\MSDS_Merck_Kaliumnitrat zur Analyse EMSURE_23.09.2021.PDF', 'C:\\Users\\abi52\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Pyprogramme\\SDBS\\MSDS_Sigma Aldrich_Ethanol_03.04.2020.pdf', 'C:\\Users\\abi52\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Pyprogramme\\SDBS\\MSDS_Thermo Fisher_Wash Solution 1 Concentrate_11.06.2019.pdf', 'C:\\Users\\abi52\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Pyprogramme\\SDBS\\TestSDS_CRC Industries_FLUX SK10_29.06.2017.PDF']
```

The error message:

```
concurrent.futures.process._RemoteTraceback: 
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\abi52\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\queues.py", line 245, in _feed
    obj = _ForkingPickler.dumps(obj)
  File "C:\Users\abi52\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 51, in dumps
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <function func at 0x000002336ED5CAF0>: attribute lookup func on __main__ failed
"""
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\abi52\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3441, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-35-a724536b8d79>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/abi52/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/PyCharm2021.3/scratches/scratch.py', wdir='C:/Users/abi52/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/PyCharm2021.3/scratches')
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2021.3.1\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_umd.py", line 198, in runfile
    pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2021.3.1\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Users/abi52/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/PyCharm2021.3/scratches/scratch.py", line 22, in <module>
    print(list(result))
  File "C:\Users\abi52\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\concurrent\futures\process.py", line 559, in _chain_from_iterable_of_lists
    for element in iterable:
  File "C:\Users\abi52\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 608, in result_iterator
    yield fs.pop().result()
  File "C:\Users\abi52\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 438, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "C:\Users\abi52\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 390, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "C:\Users\abi52\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\queues.py", line 245, in _feed
    obj = _ForkingPickler.dumps(obj)
  File "C:\Users\abi52\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 51, in dumps
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <function func at 0x000002336ED5CAF0>: attribute lookup func on __main__ failed
```

Comment: code looks okay unless `func` gets some data that I don't have. may I know the value for `PfadOrdner` and also pls let us know where you are executing it?  Is it from the terminal or some other setup? I tried your code, and it worked for me, so trying to find what is different between my run and yours.

Comment: I am using Pycharm 2021.3.1 as IDE and Python 3.9. **PfadOrdner** is the variable **path**, i wrote that wrong but edited it.

Comment: thanks! the program executes with no error for me; sorry could not recreate the error. even the [online compiler](https://onecompiler.com/python/3xptdu3b8) worked well. So not sure what going on there.

Comment: I don't know what the exact problem was, but after reinstalling my setup it worked. Thank u.

Comment: awesome! We can mark it as environmental issue :)